# Inconsistency reading from /dev/mem in Python

Tags: raspbian, python

I've posted a more generic version of this question [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893006/inconsistent-python-mmap-behaviour-with-dev-mem), but since I've had no response I'm hoping someone over this side might have an idea.

I've been working on a project in PHP which requires mmap'ing /dev/mem to gain access to the hardware peripheral registers. As there's no native mmap, I have implemented a python subprocess, which communicates with the PHP app via `stdin/stdout`.

Strangely, everything works as expected for writing, but when it comes to reading, I have a weird issue where the data coming back is

> oipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipgoipg

for as many bytes as I read.  It seems to me like it's no coincidence that this is in the `GPIO` register address space, since I have seen different repeating patterns in other address spaces.

The unusual thing is that this only occurs with `mem.read()`.  The workaround I have is by using `struct.unpack_from()`, then packing it again with `struct.pack()`.  It's slow and ugly.

```
sys.stdout.write(str(struct.pack('L', struct.unpack_from('L', mem, mem.tell())[0])))
```

From what I understood, both of those functions should be treating the stream in the same way - apparently they don't!

It's quite possible that I'm doing something completely stupid, but if someone could point it out that'd be great!

The file that contains the above issue is [here](https://github.com/calcinai/php-mmap/blob/master/subprocess/mmap-proxy.py#L27).  The project that uses it is [here](https://github.com/calcinai/phpi).

**EDIT:**

To see the issue, I've got some test code like this:

```
fd = os.open("/dev/mem", os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
mem = mmap.mmap(fd, 4096, offset=0x3f200000)
os.close(fd)

mem.seek(0x034)
bytes_read = mem.read(4)
print bytes_read

mem.seek(0x034)
bytes_unpack_pack = struct.pack('L', struct.unpack_from('L', mem, mem.tell())[0])
print bytes_unpack_pack
```

Which outputs

```
oipg
??
```

Should they not be the same?

Comment: The file link just points to another question.  I think you get the peripheral name (gpio) when you read a write only address or a reserved address within the peripheral address space.

Comment: Sorry about that, I misaligned the link number.  You're actually just the person I thought might be able to help!  Can you think of any reason then that it'd work fine one way and not the other?  The standard `mem.read()` reads exactly the same bytes as the `unpack_from()` code if I map an ordinary file.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something like using a byte offset to access a word indexed address, so you'b be trying to access word[x*4] instead of word[x].  That would account for 'gpio' being returned from invalid addresses.

Comment: I'm not sure about that - I seem to recall that I wasn't *that* far off, like the first byte was ok but not the second - I'll have to test that again tomorrow and let you know.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I've done some testing and added and example to reproduce

Comment: @joan does that make sense to you? I've tried multiple combinations of reading/seeking/dividing addresses and still no luck.